# add data-tooltip with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an attribute to an element with jQuery; since my markup is created on-the-fly I can't directly add the attribute. Why is the below script not adding the attribute? Why is this fiddle not functioning as desired? [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkdh8/12/) I am trying to get working with some sample markup included.

```
// set the tooltip content
jQuery('li#menu-item-75 a:hover:before').prop('tooltipText', 'w00t');
jQuery('li#menu-item-75 a:hover:after').prop('tooltipText', 'w00t');
```

Comment: You forgot to select jQuery on your JSFiddle...

Comment: Thanks, fixed. That's not what the problem was though.

Comment: Glad you could fix it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set the data attribute with `.attr()` in order for the DOM attribute to actually be affected:

```
jQuery('li#menu-item-75 a').attr('data-tooltip', 'w00t');
```

`:hover` and `:before`/`:after` don't work with  jQuery selectors.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fkdh8/13/**

Comment: Ok I was mixing up attr and prop. Thanks a lot!